# How to exploit x86 indirect memory operands in C program

Tags: c

I am working on x86_32 and x86_64 bit machines. Here is the problem,

```
char * p1 = malloc(10);
char * s1 = p1;
```

I.e. s1 is an alias of p1.

I have modified malloc to return a pointer X which in points to actual heap memory location and p1, s1 point to X (i.e. they dont point to X on heap directly).

I want each access on s1 and p1 (in fact each load/store on s1 and p1) to happen on X. I can not make any changes to compiler to generate appropriate code.

Do let me know if you want to know "why I am doing this" and explanations to 'Dont do this since you there is performance overhead involved' :-).

Is it possible to achieve this without taking assistance from compiler?

Comment: Does your replacement need to be named `malloc()`? Something else, like `alloc_handle()` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Mat, `malloc` returns `void*` not `char*`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: quite correct, oops :) (doesn't change the point that a `char*` is not a `char**`)

Comment: What about it :-) ? Can you be more specific, possibly an example. The basic issue here is how do make sure that every pointer dereference on returned pointer happens on actual location? Returning a value from malloc() is not an issue at all, the issue is how do you translate each access on the alias to access on heap memory i.e. X in my question.

Comment: I still don't follow the "question". What kind of memory operands are you talking about? Exploiting? In what sense? How about a better, more specific example? What's the overall goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to affect every load and store, the only way to do this (that I know of) without generating new code is by instrumenting your binary with a tool like [Pin](http://www.pintool.org/).  You will, of course, incur great amounts of overhead by instrumenting every assembly instruction.

Edit: See [here](http://www.pintool.org/docs/43611/Pin/html/) for a (possibly relevant) memory trace example.

Comment: PIN is not an option. It is too heavyweight, in fact none of the tools which do dynamic binary translation are alternatives due to significant overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy task, but you can use [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) as a library for static code analysis to introduce a stage in the compilation after pre-processing and before compilation. Your static code analysis compiler 'middleware' tool should detect calls to `malloc`, then change the types of p1 and s1, to `char **` and all places where p1 and s1 are references to *s1 and *p1, before passing the code to the compilation stage. Another option is to leverage on [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org) for the same purpose (I'm assuming you depend on gcc and not on another compiler, though).

Comment: Yes, I am using gcc so clang is not an option. Let me take a look at GCC MELT though. I had arrived at same conclusion after looking at alternatives but would still prefer some runtime hack/solution to get this done, I am not even sure that it is possible to do so at runtime. Thanks for the pointers.